# How to drop memory caches in macOS?

Tags: macos, memory, cache, virtual-memory, buffer

In GNU/Linux there's a way to `drop_caches`.

`drop_caches` is the command that would flush caches from the main memory.

I don't have such a command in macOS.

How to..?

Answer (score 8):

From the post
[echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845524/echo-3-proc-sys-vm-drop-caches-on-mac-osx):

> On OSX there is a `purge` command for that:
>
> ```
> sync && sudo purge
> ```
>
> > `sync` - force completion of pending disk writes (flush cache)
> >
> > `purge` - force disk cache to be purged (flushed and emptied)